# How many Walkers are there in Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars

Everyone knows about *AT-AT Walkers* which Luke defeated using ropes. Clone Wars fans know about four leg *AT-TE Walkers* and *AT-RT Walkers* which was one man cybernetic enhancement.

I just learned about *AT-ST Walkers*. How many Walkers are there in Star Wars universe? By Walker, I mean the vehicles which move using <s>humanoid</s> legs.

Comment: Skywalkers aren't valid...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a nice article on them [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Walker).

Turns out there are quite a few, at various times and places in the EU. Some interesting examples include:

- The OG-9 Homing Spider Droid, used by the seperatists, seen in episode 2
- The All Terrain Armoured Heavy Transport, an upgrade of the AT-AT used by Darth Krayt's Galactic Empire
- The Variable Geometry Self-Propelled Battle Droid, used by the Trade Federation, seen in episode 1
- The All Terrain Construction Transport, seen in *The Force Unleashed*

Comment: Link only answers aren't the best around here. Can you add some examples from the link?

Comment: You're right, I apologise and have added a few interesting examples.

Answer (score 1):

There are many walkers in the canon. Here's the list (by appearance titles):

- AT-PT: *Star Wars: Galactic Defense*
- Base Defense Walker: *The Force Awakens*
- Mobile Assault Walker: *The Force Awakens* Toy Line
- All Terrain Armored Cargo Transport (AT-ACT): *Rogue One*
- All Terrain Armored Transport (AT-AT): *The Empire Strikes Back*, *Return of the Jedi*, Various Books, *Star Wars Rebels*, *Battlefront*, *Star Wars: Uprising*, *Star Wars Commander*
- All Terrain Missile Platform (AT-MP): *Star Wars: Commander*
- Veteran AT-ST: *Star Wars Commander*
- All Terrain Attack Pod (AT-AP): *Revenge of the Sith*, *Star Wars: Commander*
- Elite AT-AT: *Star Wars: Commander*
- All Terrain Defense Pod (AT-DP): *Star Wars Rebels*, *Star Wars: Commander*
- All Terrain Tactical Enforcer (AT-TE): *Attack of the Clones*, *Revenge of the Sith*, *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, *Star Wars Rebels*, *Star Wars: Commander*
- All Terrain Scout Transport (AT-ST): *The Empire Strikes Back*, *Return of the Jedi*, *Star Wars: Galactic Defense*, Various Books
- All Terrain Recon Transport (AT-RT): *Revenge of the Sith*, *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, *Star Wars: Commander*
- All Terrain Open Transport (AT-OT): *Revenge of the Sith*, *Star Wars: Commander*